# Replace a section of an image using arrays in C

Tags: c

For an assignment, I've been given a rather large chunk of code that reads in a file name of a PGM image and then after running it through a function that has some for loops, it writes a new file. PGM are grayscale images that store a number 0~255 in a 2D array. I am supposed to adjust the for loops and the arrays within the function so that the new file is adjusted in some way. Here are some that I have written so far.

[image]

```
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<numRows/2;i++)
    { for (j=numCols/2;j<numCols;j++)
            {
              imgtemp[i+numRows/2-1][j+numCols/2-1] = imgtemp[i][j];
            }
    }
```

and

```
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<numRows;i++)
    { for (j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
              imgtemp[i][j] = 0;
            }
    }
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to flip selections both horizontally and vertically.

I thought it would be like this:

```
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<numRows;i++)
    { for (j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
              imgtemp[numCols-1-i][numRows-1-j] = imgtemp[i][j];
            }
    }
```

but it ends up flipping the wrong portion of the image. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If you given any of three images, you want to get the fourth, right?

Comment: we always start with the first image of the woman without any edits, so no. It would go from the starting image to the fourth image.

Comment: Is the image always square?

Comment: yes, the image will always be square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to copy values from diagonal point (`img[i][(int)(numCols*i/(float)numRows))]`) to the right. So your `j` index should start at `i*numCols/numRows`-th position. (If image is square then just simply `j = i` in the second `for`)

```
int i,j;

for (i=0;i<numRows;i++)
{
    for (j=(int)((numCols*i/(float)numRows)); j<numCols; j++)
    {
        imgtemp[numRows-1-i][numCols-1-j] = imgtemp[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you, this worked out and now I understand. I appreciate it!